# php problems with union select distinct

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose

I submitted these two files:

- [sample_annotation.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/master/mGSV/sample_annotation.txt)
- [sample_synteny.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/master/mGSV/sample_synteny.txt)

I got on the next page the following error:

```
304501820180500000018.304501820180500000018<br><br>select distinct org1,org2 from '.304501820180500000018.'_synteny union select distinct org1,org2 from '.304501820180500000018.'_synteny<br><br>

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.304501820180500000018.'_synteny union select distinct org1,org2 from '.3045018' at line 1

Whole query: select distinct org1,org2 from '.304501820180500000018.'_synteny union select distinct org1,org2 from '.304501820180500000018.'_synteny[]
```

The `mGSV/lib/data.php` looks like below and caused the above error:

```
<?php
include('database.php');

## Get parameters
$org = $_GET['org'];
$data = $_GET['data'];
$session_id = $_GET['session_id'];

$array = array();

if($data == 'annotation') {
    $query = "SELECT track_name FROM ".$session_id."_annotation WHERE org_id like '$org' GROUP BY track_name ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result != ''){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            array_push($array, $row['track_name']);
        }
    }
    //array_push($syn_array, "10_50_20_70");
}
else if ($data == 'synteny') {
    $query = "DESC ".$session_id."_synteny";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($row['Field'] == 'id'){ continue; }
        if($row['Field'] == 'blocks'){ continue; }
        if($row['Field'] == 'SYNcolor'){ continue; }
        if(! preg_match("/^org[12]+[_]?[start|end]?/", $row['Field'])){
            array_push($array, $row['Field']);
        }
    }
}
else if ($data == 'size'){
    echo "$session_id.", $session_id, "<br>";
    echo "$org", $org, "<br>";
    $query = "select distinct org1,org2 from '.$session_id.'_synteny union select distinct org1,org2 from '.$session_id.'_synteny";
    echo $query,"<br>";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo $results,"<br>";
    if ($results) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row['org1'], "<br>";
            $q = "select max(output) as max from (select max(greatest(org1_start, org1_end)) as output from ".$session_id."_synteny where org1 like '" . $row['org1'] . "' union select max(greatest(org2_start, org2_end)) as output from ".$session_id."_synteny where org2 like '" . $row['org1'] . "') as t1";
            echo $q, "<br>";
            $res = mysql_query($q);
            if (!$res) {
                die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo $row['org1'],"<br>";
            echo $row['org2'],"<br>";
            if (! isset($array[$row['org1']])){
                //echo "add<br>";
                $array[$row['org1']] = mysql_result($res,0);
            }
            $q = "select max(output) as max from (select max(greatest(org1_start, org1_end)) as output from ".$session_id."_synteny where org1 like '" . $row['org2'] . "' union select max(greatest(org2_start, org2_end)) as output from ".$session_id."_synteny where org2 like '" . $row['org2'] . "') as t1";
            #echo $q, "<br>";
            $res = mysql_query($q);
            if (!$res) {
                die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
            }
            if (! isset($array[$row['org2']])){
                //echo "add<br>";
                $array[$row['org2']] = mysql_result($res,0);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
        echo 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    }
}
else if ($data == 'order'){
    $query = "select distinct org1 from ".$session_id."_synteny union select distinct org2 from ".$session_id."_synteny ";
    //echo $query,"<br>";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $default = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($default, $row['org1']);
    }
    $array = join('__ORDER__', $default);
}
else if ($data == 'sorder'){
    $query = "select distinct org1,org2 from ".$session_id."_synteny union select distinct org1,org2 from ".$session_id."_synteny ";
    //echo $query,"<br>";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $default = array();
    $assarr = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if( ! in_array($row['org1'], $default)){
            array_push($default, $row['org1']);
            $assarr[sizeof($assarr)] = array();
        }
        if( ! in_array($row['org2'], $default)){
            array_push($default, $row['org2']);
            $assarr[sizeof($assarr)] = array();
        }
        $len_query = "select sum(org1_end) - sum(org1_start) + sum(org2_end) - sum(org1_start) as sum from ".$session_id."_synteny where (org1 like '".$row['org1']."' and org2 like '".$row['org2']."') OR (org1 like '".$row['org2']."' and org2 like '".$row['org1']."')";
        $q_result = mysql_query($len_query);
        $q_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_result);
        #echo $len_query,"<br>";
        #echo $q_row['sum'],"<br>";
        $assarr[array_search($row['org1'], $default)][array_search($row['org2'], $default)] = $q_row['sum'];
        #$assarr[array_search($row['org1'], $default)][array_search($row['org2'], $default)] = 1;
        $assarr[array_search($row['org2'], $default)][array_search($row['org1'], $default)] = $q_row['sum'];
        #$assarr[array_search($row['org2'], $default)][array_search($row['org1'], $default)] = 1;
        #echo array_search($row['org1'], $default) . "][ ". array_search($row['org2'], $default) . '<br>';
        $assarr[array_search($row['org1'], $default)][array_search($row['org1'], $default)] = 0;
        #echo array_search($row['org1'], $default) . "][ ". array_search($row['org1'], $default) . '<br>';
        $assarr[array_search($row['org2'], $default)][array_search($row['org2'], $default)] = 0;
        #echo array_search($row['org2'], $default) . "][ ". array_search($row['org2'], $default) . '<br>';
    }

    $a = FindOrder($assarr);
    $sugg = array();
    //echo sizeof($a),'<br>';
    foreach($a as $b){
        //echo $default[$b],"<br>";
        array_push($sugg, $default[$b]);
    }
    $array = join('__ORDER__', $sugg);
}


function FindOrder($graph){
    $r = array();
    $last = -1;
    while(!isEmpty($graph)){
        $start = leastEdges($graph);
        $path = longestPath($graph, $start, 0);
        $path = completeCycle($graph, $path);
        if($path[0] != $last){
            array_push($r, $path[0]);
        }
        for($x = 1; $x < sizeof($path); $x++){
            array_push($r, $path[$x]);
        }
        $last = $path[sizeof($path)-1];
        $graph = removePath($graph, $path);
    }
    return $r;
}

function longestPath($graph, $cur, $len){
    $path = array();
    array_push($path, $cur);
    $longestSubpath = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($graph); $x++){
        if($graph[$cur][$x] != 0){
            $subpath = longestPath(removeVertex($graph, $cur), $x, $len + $graph[$cur][$x]);
            if(sizeof($subpath) > sizeof($longestSubpath)){
                $longestSubpath = $subpath;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($longestSubpath as $x){
        array_push($path, $x);
    }
    return $path;
}

function completeCycle($graph, $path){
    $graph = removePath($graph, $path);
    $last = $path[sizeof($path)-1];
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($graph); $x++){
        if($graph[$last][$x] != 0){
            array_push($path, $x);
            return $path;
        }
    }
    return $path;
}

function removePath($graph, $path){
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($path) - 1; $x++){
        $arr = $path[$x]; //***forgot the $ in front of path***
        $b = $path[$x+1]; //***forgot the $ in front of path***
        $graph[$arr][$b] = 0;
        $graph[$b][$arr] = 0;
    }
    return $graph;
}

function removeVertex($graph, $vtx){
    if($vtx < 0 || $vtx >= sizeof($graph)){
        return copy($graph);
    }
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($graph); $x++){
        $graph[$x][$vtx] = 0;
        $graph[$vtx][$x] = 0;
    }
    return $graph;
}

function numEdges($vtx){
    $r = 0;
    foreach($vtx as $x){
        if($x != 0){
            $r++;
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

function leastEdges($graph){
    $r = -1;
    $min = 2147483647;
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($graph); $x++){
        $e = numEdges($graph[$x]);
        if($e != 0 && $e < $min){
            $r = $x;
            $min = $e;
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

function isEmpty($arr){
    $r = true;
    foreach($arr as $x){
        $r = $r && numEdges($x) == 0;
    }
    return $r;
}

## Return the JSON object
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

I created a docker-compose.yml and the can be run in the following way:

```
git clone https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker.git
docker-compose up --build
```

The service can be accessed via `localhost` and PhpMyAdmin can be accessed via `localhost:8183`

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi kindly var_dump(); your query and post it here so we can further help you since it's a Query problem

Comment: Where should I insert var_dump() and what should I pass to it?

Comment: var_dump( $query);die(); insert it on your if else conditions before  mysql_query($query);

Comment: i got `string(135) "select distinct org1,org2 from '.304342020180200000016.'_synteny union select distinct org1,org2 from '.304342020180200000016.'_synteny"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run independently both query in your Mysql phpmyadmin

```
select distinct org1,org2 from '.304342020180200000016.'_synteny

select distinct org1,org2 from '.304342020180200000016.'_synteny
```

As i see your query seems to be correct since union requires the same numbers of columns and same data type.

And why is your table name in the union query is both the same.

Comment: Your both queries look the same and running them individually I got `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.304342020180200000016.'_synteny LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`. I am not quite sure why my table name in the union query is both the same because I forked the code from [here](https://github.com/qunfengdong/mGSV) and now I just try to get to run it in docker.

Comment: Try to remove the single quote '.

Comment: `select distinct org1,org2 from .304342020180200000016._synteny` caused `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.304342020180200000016._synteny LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1`.

Comment: is this a 304342020180200000016 a database ?

Comment: Try this -> select distinct org1,org2 from 304342020180200000016._synteny

Comment: Did not work, but `select distinct org1,org2 from 304342020180200000016_synteny` returned `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). `

Comment: Okay . Now tell me what is 304342020180200000016 and this _synteny . 

304342020180200000016 -> is this a database since originally you use . to separate this 304342020180200000016 and _synteny
and is this a table _synteny ? 

or This is a is just a table as a whole 304342020180200000016_synteny ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `304420020185300000016_annotation`` gives me rows of values (`org_id, start, end, strand, feature_name, feature_value, track_name, track_shape, track_color`) but `SELECT * FROM `304420020185300000016_synteny`` contains only the column names (`org1, org1_start, org1_end, org2, org2_start, org2_end, length, SYNcolor`) without any data. Now, I think the problem happens during the loading the file into the database.

Comment: Okay. 304420020185300000016_annotation is a table with values and 304420020185300000016_synteny has no current values yet

Comment: yes, but 304420020185300000016_synteny  should have values because during the parsing I got the following output `insert command: insert into 304420020185300000016_synteny (org1, org1_start, org1_end, org2, org2_start, org2_end, length, SYNcolor) VALUES('Organism_A','25787','22159','Organism_B','18060','25102','20','3.0E-3','3629','#8953BA') ....`

Comment: p.s. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607448/phps-execute-sql-did-not-insert-data-into-the-database). Thank you for your help

Comment: Okay. Good job. Thank you too.