# php's execute_sql did not insert data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, docker-compose

I submitted these two files:

- [sample_annotation.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/master/mGSV/sample_annotation.txt)
- [sample_synteny.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker/master/mGSV/sample_synteny.txt)

It appears that `sample_synteny.txt` has not be loaded into the `mgsv` database with help of `function syn($filename)` because `SELECT * FROM` 304420020185300000016_synteny`` contains only the column names (`org1, org1_start, org1_end, org2, org2_start, org2_end, length, SYNcolor`) without any data. During processing this file I got the following output:

```
insert into 304530020182800000020_synteny (org1, org1_start, org1_end, org2, org2_start, org2_end, length, SYNcolor) VALUES('Organism_A','25787','22159','Organism_B','18060','25102','20','3.0E-3','3629','#8953BA')
...
```

On the other hand, `sample_annotation.txt` has been loaded into the `mgsv` database with help of `function annotation($annfilename)` because `SELECT * FROM` 304420020185300000016_annotation`` gives me rows of values (`org_id, start, end, strand, feature_name, feature_value, track_name, track_shape, track_color`). During processing this file I got the following output:

```
insert into 304500120185700000019_annotation (org_id, start, end, strand, feature_name, feature_value, track_name, track_shape, track_color) VALUES('Organism_C','42','3972','+','XG001','','gene','arrow','brown')
...
```

The `mgsv/index.php` looks like below and caused the above error:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect($database_host, $database_user, $database_pass);
if($link == FALSE){
    echo 'Cannot connect to database';
}

@mysql_select_db($database_name) or die("Unable to connect to database");

function execute_sql($sql){
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    return $result;
}

function synteny_table($newsession_id, $synfilename) {
    ## initialize bool
    $bool = 'true';
    
    ## Get the first line of the file
    $header_line = exec("head -n 1 tmp/" . $newsession_id . $synfilename);
    ## split the line into items
    $header_pieces = explode("\t",$header_line);
    
    ## the file header line is good
    if( $bool == 'true'){
        ## Initialize a string to create fields for additional columns
        $userdef = "";
        ## Iterate from the 7th column till the end
        for( $i = 6; $i < count( $header_pieces); $i++){
            $userdef .= "`".$header_pieces[$i]."`"."varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
        }
        ## Check if there is a length function
        $check_length = array_search('length', $header_pieces);
        ## if not create a column
        if($check_length == '') {
            $userdef .= "`length` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,";
        }
        ## get the create statement
        $createTable = "CREATE TABLE `{$newsession_id}_synteny` (
            `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `org1` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `org1_start` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `org1_end` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `org2` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
            `org2_start` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
            `org2_end` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
            $userdef
            `SYNcolor` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
            KEY `org1_start` (`org1_start`),
            KEY `org1_end` (`org1_end`),
            KEY `org2_start` (`org2_start`),
            KEY `org2_end` (`org2_end`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;";
        ## execute the 
        $result = mysql_query($createTable);
        if(! $result){
            $bool = "Unable to create the synteny table.<br>" . mysql_error();
        }
    }
    ## return the boolean information
    return $bool;
}

function desc_synteny_table($newsession_id) {
    $cnames = array();
    $sql = "DESCRIBE `{$newsession_id}_synteny`";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if( ! $result){
        return mysql_error();
    }
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
        array_push($cnames, $row['Field']);
    }
    return $cnames;
}

function getRandomColorHex($max_r = 255, $max_g = 255, $max_b = 255) {
    return sprintf( '#%02X%02X%02X', rand(0,$max_r), rand(0,$max_g), rand(0,$max_b) );
}

function syn($filename) {
    $bool_page = 'true';
    #echo "($filename[0])<br>";
    ## Get the global values
    global $upload_dir, $newsession_id, $email;
    #echo "($upload_dir)<br>";
    ## Get the first line
    $header_line = exec( "head -n 1 mgsv/tmp/".$newsession_id . $filename);
    if($header_line == ''){
        $bool_page = 'Synteny file: Unable to store in /tmp folder.';
        return $bool_page;
    }
    ## convert into array
    $header_pieces = explode( "\t", $header_line);

    ## check if the first item starts with #
    if( ! preg_match("/^#/i", $header_pieces[0])) {
        $bool_page = 'Synteny file: The # symbol at line 1 is not present.';
        return $bool_page;
    }

    ## Replace the # for further analysis
    $header_pieces[0] = str_replace('#', '', $header_pieces[0]);

    ## Get the fixed column names
    $fixed_org = array('org1', 'org1_start', 'org1_end', 'org2', 'org2_start', 'org2_end');

    ## Check if the header matches our column names
    ## for each fixed name
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fixed_org); $i++){
        ## if the fixed name doesnt match the file column name
        if( $header_pieces[$i] != $fixed_org[$i]) {
            ## raise error
            $bool_page = "Synteny file: Column No." . ($i + 1) . " header should be '" . $fixed_org[$i] . "'.";
            return $bool_page;
        }
    }

    ## Check if the number of columns is the same as column headers
    $second_line = exec( "head -n 2 mgsv/tmp/" . $newsession_id . $filename . "| tail -n 1");
    $second_pieces = explode( "\t", $second_line);
    if( sizeof($header_pieces) != sizeof($second_pieces)){
        $bool_page = "Synteny file: There are " . sizeof($header_pieces) . " column names but " . sizeof($second_pieces) . " columns.";
        return $bool_page;
    }

    ## For the non-fixed column names
    for($i = 6; $i < sizeof($header_pieces); $i++){
        ## make sure they are not empty
        if( preg_match("/^\s*$/i", $header_pieces[$i])) {
            $bool_page = "Synteny file: Column No." . ($i + 1) . " header is blank.";
            return $bool_page;
        }
    }

    ## Check if the column names are unique
    if( count( array_unique( $header_pieces)) < count( $header_pieces)) {
        $bool_page = 'Synteny file: There are more than one column with the same name';
        return $bool_page;
    }

    ## create the table in the database
    $bool_page = synteny_table( $newsession_id, $filename);
    if($bool_page != 'true'){
        return $bool_page;
    }

    ## Get the field names
    $cnames = desc_synteny_table($newsession_id);
    if(is_string($cnames)){
        return $cnames;
    }

    ## Remove the id field name
    array_shift($cnames);
    ## get a string from the array
    $insert_into = implode(', ', $cnames);


    ## look for column name 'length'
    $check_length = array_search('length', $header_pieces);

    ## define pattern
    $pattern = '/^.*\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+\t.*\t[0-9]+\t[0-9]+';

    ## Get the starting index of the new items
    $newitems = count($header_pieces) - 7;
    ## If no addition items are provided
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $newitems; $i++) {
        ## generate the regex for each additional column
        $pattern .= '\t[0-9\.Ee\-\+]*';
    }
    ## close the $pattern here.
    $pattern .= '$/';

    ## create a read file handle to the uplaoded file
    $fh = fopen($upload_dir . $newsession_id . $filename, "r");
    ## Remove the first line
    fgets($fh);

    ## initialize a line_number to know
    $line_number = 1;
    while( ! feof( $fh)){
        ## increment it
        $line_number++;
        ## get each line
        $line = fgets($fh);
        ## continue if it is an empty line
        if($line == ''){ continue; }
        ## trim for end of line characters
        $line = trim($line);
        ## compare with the pattern
        $correct_format = preg_match($pattern, $line);
        if($correct_format == false){
            $bool_page = "Synteny File: line number $line_number, is not in the correct format";
            break;
        }
        #echo "($line)<br>";
        $values = "VALUES(";
        $num_of_items = explode("\t", $line);
        for ($jj = 0; $jj < count($num_of_items); $jj++) {
            $values .= "'" . $num_of_items[$jj] . "',";
        }
        ## check for the first 250 characters of org1 and org2
        if(substr($num_of_items[0], 0, 250) == substr($num_of_items[3], 0, 250)){
            ## If they are similar they throw an error and quit
            $bool_page = "Synteny File: Org1 and Org2 are similar at line $line_number.";
            break;
        }
        ## If there is no column called length in the input synteny file
        if($check_length == false){
            ## get the difference between start and end of org2
            $org2 = abs($num_of_items[4] - $num_of_items[5]) + 1;
            ## get the difference between start and end of org1
            $org1 = abs($num_of_items[1] - $num_of_items[2]) + 1;
            ## get the minimum of the above two lengths
            $minlength = min($org1, $org2);
            ## concatenate this minimum value to the input command
            $values .= "'" . $minlength . "',";
        }
        ## generate a random color to store each synteny
        $values .= "'" .  getRandomColorHex() . "')";

        ## If everything is good
        if( $bool_page == 'true'){
            ## Insert the values into the table
            $sql = "insert into {$newsession_id}_synteny ($insert_into) $values";
            ## show the statement
            #echo "insert command: $sql<br>";
            ## execute the statement
            $result = execute_sql($sql);
        }
    }
    ## Delete the files from server
    if(file_exists($upload_dir . $newsession_id . $filename)){
        unlink($upload_dir . $newsession_id . $filename);
    }
    ## return the boolean parameter
    return $bool_page;
}
```

I created a docker-compose.yml and the can be run in the following way:

```
git clone https://github.com/mictadlo/mGSV-docker.git
docker-compose up --build
```

The service can be accessed via `localhost` and PhpMyAdmin can be accessed via `localhost:8183`

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the problem your having.  There is way to much code to effectively deal with.

Comment: I reduced the amount of code.

Comment: Looks as though your inserting the actual values into your SQL statements, you should use prepared statements and bound values as this stops problems where your values contain certain characters (quotes etc.)

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: There are loads around - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019826/php-generate-dynamic-pdo-insert, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358874/dynamic-prepared-insert-statement?rq=1

Comment: Try to execute this on your phpadmin .

insert into 304500120185700000019_annotation (org_id, start, end, strand, feature_name, feature_value, track_name, track_shape, track_color) VALUES('Organism_C','42','3972','+','XG001','','gene','arrow','brown')

Then post the error you encounter

Comment: It gave me  Unexpected token. (near "_synteny" at position 33)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "_synteny" at position 33),  (near "org1" at position 43), (near "org1_start" at position 49), (near "org1_end" at position 61), (near "org2" at position 71), (near "org2_start" at position 77),  (near "org2_end" at position 89), (near "length" at position 99)

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1